# Which engine is better at Chess960-Stockfish or Leela?

Tags: engines, stockfish, chess960, leela

It seems that TCEC has seen Stockfish and Leela go back and forth. It is probable that these days Stockfish is a little bit better than Leela. I was wondering, since it is different in Chess960, which one of two is better at it? Does anyone have any insights?

Comment: i think it would come down to the matter of time. given more time stockfish will perform better or equal to leela

Comment: afaik Leela trained a network especially on chess960 so I assume it would win

Comment: Occasionally, TCEC hosts games of 960. If you ask nicely, you may be able to get an exhibition.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, it's Stockfish: in the latest FRC exhibition (November 2020) [Stockfish beat Leela +8 -0 =42](https://tcec-chess.com/#div=frc2f&game=1&season=19).

Answer (score -2):

Leela or AlphaZero is the best computer since they have beaten Stockfish in standard chess and Leela is said to be better at positional chess than Stockfish. Stockfish is better at tactical chess and since Chess960 is more positional than standard chess, Leela (or AlphaZero) is better at Chess960.

Comment: In the recent TCEC match, Stockfish beat Leela again. Anyway this is too simplistic, you can 't really split chess in "positional chess" and "tactical chess" and there is no reason to assume Chess960 is more one than the other.